# Set cookie using watir webdriver or selenium

Tags: ruby, cookies, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

Creation of driver:-

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new 

driver = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, profile: profile

url= 'http://www.example.com'
```

Adding cookies:-

```
driver.cookies.add("test","1",{expires: 10.days.from_now})

driver.goto url
```

My cookies not returned in the response.

If i add domain in cookies.

```
driver.cookies.add("test","1",{expires: 10.days.from_now, domain: 'example.com'})
```

its saying errors like below:-

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidCookieDomainError: You may only set cookies for the current domain
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to be on the domain you're setting the cookie for, so try:

```
driver.goto url
driver.cookies.add("test","1",{expires: 10.days.from_now})
```

Now it should show up when  on the same domain you do:

```
driver.cookies.to_a
```

That is assuming you've required active_support/time (to make the expiry work).

Comment: I have tried your solution.But still i get  error as "You may only set cookies on html documents"

Comment: Is the page loaded? You might get that error if the browser is still on about:blank.

Comment: Can you tell me what the url is you're using? If not, do you also get the error when using example.com as in your question? If everything is fine when using your example, which works fine for me, then the issue is the url.

Comment: Yes its working with example.com but not working with my URL.